# How to extract each level in nested array to separated arrays with specific key-value pairs?

Tags: php

I've got a 4-level nested array, each level represent a hiereachy in an organization. Each level's key is the hierarchy value, and inside it there is the id of it in the array. The last level is only the value-id pair:

```
$data =  [
    "top_level_data1" => [ 
            'top_level_id' => 0,           
            'sub_level_1' => [ 
                    'sub_level_1_id' => 0,                      
                    'sub_level_2_data1' => [
                            'sub_level_2_id' => 0,
                            'sub_level_2_data' => [
                                      0 => "some_val"
                                      1 => "some_other_val"
                                 ]
                        ]
              ]
        ],
    "top_level_data2" => [  
            'level_1_id' => 1,            
            'sub_level_1_other' => [      
                    'sub_level_1_id' => 1,              
                    'sub_level_2_data2' => [
                            'sub_level_2_id' => 1,
                            'sub_level_3_data1' => [
                                      2 => "another_val"
                                      3 => "bar"
                                      4 => "foo"
                                 ]
                        ],
                    'sub_level_2_data3' => [
                            'sub_level_2_id' => 2,
                            'sub_level_3_data2' => [
                                      5 => "foobar"
                                      6 => "hello"
                                      7 => "goodbye"
                                 ]
                        ]
              ]
        ] 
];
```

I want to extract it to separate arrays that would contain the hierarchy value-id pairs.

Expected output from the above example (without the `id`s of the above level):

```
$top_level = [
     0 => "top_level_data1",
     1 => "top_level_data2"
]

$sub_level_1 = [
    0 => "sub_level_1",
    1 => "sub_level_1_other"
]

$sub_level_2 = [
    0 => "sub_level_2_data1",
    1 => "sub_level_2_data2",
    2 => "sub_level_2_data3"
]

$sub_level_3 = [
    0 => "some_val"
    1 => "some_other_val"
    2 => "another_val"
    3 => "bar"
    4 => "foo"
    5 => "foobar"
    6 => "hello"
    7 => "goodbye"
]
```

I've tried using the `RecursiveIterator` but that does not work (At first I wanted to use it just to check if it iterates correctly, even before assignting the key-values as I wanted, but it just doesn't do it as I wanted):

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data));
foreach($it as $key => $val) {
    $level[$it->getDepth()][] = $val;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you have any **specific** question about this?

Comment: added code, I tried using the RecursiveIterator, and although it does seem to iterate for a few levels correctly, something breaks for the last level, I assume because the last level is not arrays but just key-values. I will have to use another method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can do it:

```
$result = [];
$recursive = null;
$recursive = function($args,$level=0) use (&$recursive,&$result){
    foreach($args as $k=>$v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            $result[$level][]=$k;
            $recursive($v,$level+1);
        } else if(is_string($v)){
            $result[$level][]=$v;
        }
    }
};
$recursive($data);
var_export($result);
```

But your expected output isn't ok. Because i think *sub_level_2_data* must be *sub_level_3_data* (in the $data array above). And the hole `sub_level_3*`level is missing in your expected output.

With this code you get an result array instead of separate filled variables.

Will not explain it in detail, but try to understand whats happening here and you can learn some new php stuff.

Comment: this works like a charm, thank you. I tried to use the `RecursiveIterator` as you can see, but you just made a "native" recursive function